# Rewrite and change site url Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I read all the discussions here on stack overflow but did not help me.

Let me explain what I would like to do:

I have a redirect from www.site1.it at www.site2.it Thanks to my hosting I can do a hidden redirect and keep the url "site1.it" when I reach "site2.it".

The problem is that my hosting inserts an iframe by including all the site disabling the responsive. I would like to know if there is a way to keep the same url after the redirect, make a hidden redirect.

ps. When I go to https://www.site2.it, the url must remain the same as it already is. I'm sorry for the link size but I do not have 10 reputation points.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ever heard of aliases? And I am sorry, what would be the point of redirecting from s1 to s2, but you want to reach s2?

Comment: In reality no. It's a customer request. I have an aruba hosting that allows this hidden redirection but it inserts this frame and the responsive does not work anymore. For this problem I look for an alternative code solution. ps. I want to reach s2 while keeping the s1 as url. I don't know if I explained it well

Comment: No i mean why do you want to access s1 from s2? if it is part of your site then put in the same directory. Otherwise it is not possible without a new stream (frame) except htaccess

Comment: Thank you for answering. My client wants to redirect users visiting site = site1 to the new site = site2. When they come from site = site1, once they are redirected to the new site, they will need to see the old url. I do not even know if this is possible. It's not a very trivial thing so maybe I did not explain it well. ps. Sites are on two separate domains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to changes 2 values in the database (site_url & base_url) (wp_options) and eventually create a proper DNS redirection in your hosting.

You can also check your wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

The "hidden redirect" won't help you, they are usually based on frames or iframes, and will mess with your site.

You can however use a reverse proxy. If mod_proxy is enabled, you can ask mod_rewrite to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [P,L]
```

The client will not see that the request is proxied to another host (even if it's on the same server in your case). However, if links, CSS, JS and images are referenced with host (e.g. http://example.org/myimage.jpg instead of /myimage.jpg), you will have to add more magic. In that case it's probably easiest to set WP_HOME / WP_SITEURL on the target-site to the old address for proxied requests (you can probably recognize those by the REMOTE_ADDR).